# Error al generar archivos .txt con la librería "fstream" en c++

Tags: c++, fstream

Tengo un problema al generar archivos con la librería `<fstream>`. Se puden generar archivos sin extensión, pero al agregar la extensión .txt no se genera ningún archivo.

El código que tengo es el de acá abajo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream archivo("holaMundo.txt");
    if(archivo.is_open())
        archivo << "HOLA MUNDO" << endl;
    else
        cout << "ERROR AL GENERAR" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Lo curioso es que hace poco el código funcionaba bien.

Comment: Tu codigo funciona a la perfeccion en mi maquina, creo que tu problema esta en otro lado.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que Windows por defecto oculta las extensiones de archivo. Igual tienes el holamundo.txt allí y lo que ves es solo holamundo con un icono de texto.